# how to open drawer without navigating to the screen from one of the tabs of tabnavigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I am trying to open up the drawer from one my tab called profile as shown in below. When I click on the profile tab it opens up the HomeScreen from ProfileNavigator. Which is right, but I wanna prevent that and only open the drawer with out a default navigation. How do I do it? Also ProfileNavigator is preventing to open my next tab which is Home, any idea why? But I am able to tab of Histroy screen then can come back to Home screen.

```
const ProfileNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
  },
  Notifications: {
    screen: ExampleScreen,
  }
});

const DashboardTabNav = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Profile: {
    screen: ProfileNavigator,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      tabBarOnPress: (tab) => {
        navigation.openDrawer();
      }
    })
  },
  Home: Dashboard,
  History: SettingsScreen,
  Cart: CartScreen
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Ahh, fixed it.
Incase someone looking for an example,
You need to add the createDrawerNavigator inside the createBottomTabNavigator. I was doing it the otherway.
For example,

```
const ProfileNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Drawer: DashboardTabNav
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Drawer',
  contentComponent: ExampleScreen,
  drawerWidth: 300

});

// Manifest of possible screens
const PrimaryNav = createStackNavigator({
  DashboardScreen: { screen: ProfileNavigator },
  LoginScreen: { screen: LoginScreen },
  LaunchScreen: { screen: LaunchScreen },
  UpdateUserScreen: { screen: UpdateUserScreen }
}, {
  // Default config for all screens
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'LoginScreen',
  navigationOptions: {
    headerStyle: styles.header
  }
});
export default createAppContainer(PrimaryNav);
```

Comment: It gives an error like profile must be a React component.

Comment: You aren't passing a valid component.

Comment: APIs have changed  Goodluck