# React-Navigation adding drawer navigation with tab

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I'm using react-navigation ("^3.0.9") with expo.

This is my logic flow:

```
TabView(BottomTabNavigator) with StackNavigatior:

HomeStack
 --HomeScreen
 ...
LinksStack
 --LinkScreen
 ...
SettingsStack
-- Aboutscreen
...
```

Everything works ok, but now I would like to add a drawer navigation (hamburger menu) as follows:

```
DrawerNavigation View
  --HomeScreen(which will show HomeScreen with 3 tabs)
  --Screen2 (no tabs)
  --Screen3 (no tabs)
```

Which I tried to do the following:

```
export const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeStack,
  LinksStack,
  SettingsStack,
}
);

export const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
  HomeScreen: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Screen2: { screen: Screen2 },
  Screen3: { screen: Screen3 },
});
```

> which they returned an error of undefined is not a function

the original code was to export the default bottom tab navigator only like,

```
//export default createBottomTabNavigator({
//   HomeStack,
//   LinksStack,
//   SettingsStack,
// }
// );
```

> How do I implement both BottomTabNavigator and DrawerNavigator together?

--Code as below

My App.js which calls AppNavigator

```
render() {
    if (!this.state.isLoadingComplete && !this.props.skipLoadingScreen) {
      return (
        <AppLoading
          startAsync={this._loadResourcesAsync}
          onError={this._handleLoadingError}
          onFinish={this._handleFinishLoading}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
          <AppNavigator />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

which AppNavigator calls MainTabNavigator

```
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import MainTabNavigator from './MainTabNavigator';

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator({
  Main: MainTabNavigator,
}
));
```

an example of my stackNavigator with Tab

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  HomeDetail: HomeDetailScreen
});

HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Home',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? `ios-home`
          : 'md-home'
      }
    />
  ),
};
```

Update: 
I have done a correct working [snack example](http://snack.expo.io/@stingray91/courageous-sandwich) in which anyone can reference from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the tabNavigator inside the DrawerNavigator.

```
const ProfileNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Drawer: DashboardTabNav
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Drawer',
  contentComponent: ExampleScreen,
  drawerWidth: 300

});

// Manifest of possible screens
const PrimaryNav = createStackNavigator({
  DashboardScreen: { screen: ProfileNavigator },
  LoginScreen: { screen: LoginScreen },
  LaunchScreen: { screen: LaunchScreen },
  UpdateUserScreen: { screen: UpdateUserScreen }
}, {
  // Default config for all screens
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'LoginScreen',
  navigationOptions: {
    headerStyle: styles.header
  }
});
export default createAppContainer(PrimaryNav);
```

Take a look at [how to open drawer without navigating to the screen from one of the tabs of tabnavigator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54580896/how-to-open-drawer-without-navigating-to-the-screen-from-one-of-the-tabs-of-tabn)
or
https://readybytes.in/blog/how-to-integrate-tabs-navigation-drawer-navigation-and-stack-navigation-together-in-react-navigation-v2
Also for full example take a look at https://gitlab.com/readybytes/ReactNavigationExampleVersion2

Comment: Hi , i believe my react-navigation is version 3, not 2.

Comment: This will still work. I am using `"react-navigation": "3.0.0"` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54580896/how-to-open-drawer-without-navigating-to-the-screen-from-one-of-the-tabs-of-tabn
This one I posted this week. I faced the same issue. Then this repo helped me to fix this.
The above code exactly copied from my codebase.

Comment: `const DashboardTabNav = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Profile: {
    screen: ProfileScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      tabBarOnPress: (tab) => {
        navigation.openDrawer();
      }
    })
  },
  Home: Dashboard,
  History: SettingsScreen,
  Cart: CartScreen
},
{
  defaultNavigationOptions: customTabs,
  animationEnabled: true,
  swipeEnabled: true,
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  initialRouteName: 'Cart',
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#6C1D7C',
    inactiveTintColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
    showLabel: false,
  },
});`

Comment: If you are still confused add up a small example in https://snack.expo.io/
I will help you with your code.

Comment: I made an example snack , in case anyone want to live working demo using expo https://snack.expo.io/@cjmling/react-tab-and-drawer