# Bottom Tab Navigator with Drawer Navigator React Native

Tags: react-native, navigation

I've created drawer navigator in tab navigator now I've 2 problems about it I need assistance with,

- Firstly, Drawer Navigator isn't accessible in other two tabs.
- Secondly, I want to redirect user to first screen of drawer on double click of bottom navigator first item i.e. ABOUT.

  ```
  const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
   ABOUT: MyDrawerNavigator,
   Who: WhoScreen,
   What: WhatScreen,
  },

  const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
   {

   AimOfSeminar: {
   navigationOptions: { drawerLabel: 'Aim of Seminar' },
   screen: AimScreen,
   },
   ConceptNote: {
   screen: ConceptScreen,
   },

  Speakers: SpeakerTab,
  MediaCoverage: {
  screen: MediaCoverageScreen,
  }, 
  },
  }
  ```

  What I want is:
- Bottom Tab Navigator accessible on all screens. (1)
- Drawer Navigator accessible on all tabs.
- Go to main route of first tab on double click.
- Make Drawer preview on top of bottom tab navigator by current setting bottom navigator appears on top, if I rearrange navigators I get drawer navigator on top but it generates problem (1) of above list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-Navigation adding drawer navigation with tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54643648/react-navigation-adding-drawer-navigation-with-tab)

Comment: No, you see if I shift tabNavigator in DrawerNavigator it only shifts the problem, with it I can't access Tab Navigator in other Drawer Navigator screens.
Currently, I cant access drawer navigator in tab navigator other tabs

Comment: Did you finally found a solution to your problem @Swair.a ? I would like to see a concrete example.

Comment: @RaKoDev No, we didn't actually solve it, but we worked it around a bit and that wasn't best of solutions according to performance and everything. We dynamically created a bottom bar in each drawer item, which visibly solved the issue. (Won't recommend using it)